# EC2 firewall scope

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I setup EC2 firewall settings, what is the scope of the firewall? Suppose I don't open port 8080 to the public, but I would like to be able to push SNS messages to a EC2 HTTP endpoint on 8080, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope is whatever you set it to. In the "source" field, just set it to whatever host (or subnet) you want to allow traffic from. If it's a single host, then specify `/32` as the netmask. If you want to allow from all hosts, set it to `0.0.0.0/0`.

With regards to receiving SNS notifications, you'll likely need to ask Amazon if they're able to provide you the subnet(s) that SNS notifications are sent from.

Comment: Ok, so the firewall is on the machine, and not an Amazon wide firewall.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Amazon wide firewall", but yes, security group ACLs apply directly to EC2 instances, or more accurately, they likely act within the Xen network stack of the host machine.